# Flutter Installation Problem on Windows 10

Tags: flutter, mobile

i’ve just started learning flutter and in the installation phase.
I faced a problem i extracted the flutter sdk folder in my `C:/Users` (didn’t put it in the program file folder)

- I set my environment variable in the path , but when i run any flutter command like (flutter doctor or flutter) nothing happened no output literally nothing it keeps hanging
  -I tried the same thing inside the bin folder i run the flutter Batch file and still the same issue

Any help please !!!

Comment: did you restart the device? if not, try it

Comment: You must set system environment path variable with **C:\Users\flutter\bin** 
then restart all your terminals.

Comment: i did but still didn't fix the problem